# How to get auto generated id from room database in java?

Tags: android

I have table in which i have a customer id column which is auto generated no whenever user inserts its details a new auto generated id is inserted in database.my concern is how can i get that id once user click on save detail.I have gone through stack overflow before but i don't found any solution.Also i want to know that i have  Setter-method in entity class for id but when i fetch value  it always show 0.

Entity class

```
@Entity
public class CustomerDetails  {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Customer_Id")
    private int CustomerId;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Customer_FirstName")
    private  String CustomerFirstName;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Customer_LastName")
    private  String CustomerLastName;
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Customer_PhoneNumber")
    private  String CustomerPhoneNo;
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Customer_Address")
    private  String CustomerAddress;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Created_At",defaultValue = "CURRENT_DATETIME")
    @TypeConverters(TimestampConverter.class)
    private Date createdAt;

    public CustomerDetails(@NonNull String customerFirstName, @NonNull String customerLastName, @NonNull String customerPhoneNo, @NonNull String customerAddress, Date createdAt) {
        CustomerFirstName = customerFirstName;
        CustomerLastName = customerLastName;
        CustomerPhoneNo = customerPhoneNo;
        CustomerAddress = customerAddress;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public CustomerDetails() {
    }

    public int getCustomerId() {
        return CustomerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
       CustomerId = customerId;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getCustomerFirstName() {
        return CustomerFirstName;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getCustomerLastName() {
        return CustomerLastName;
    }



    @NonNull
    public String getCustomerAddress() {
        return CustomerAddress;
    }

    @NonNull
    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCustomerFirstName(@NonNull String customerFirstName) {
        CustomerFirstName = customerFirstName;
    }

    public void setCustomerLastName(@NonNull String customerLastName) {
        CustomerLastName = customerLastName;
    }


    public void setCustomerAddress(@NonNull String customerAddress) {
        CustomerAddress = customerAddress;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(@NonNull Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getCustomerPhoneNo() {
        return CustomerPhoneNo;
    }

    public void setCustomerPhoneNo(@NonNull String customerPhoneNo) {
        CustomerPhoneNo = customerPhoneNo;
    }
}
```

DAO interface

```
    @Dao
public interface CustomerDetailsDAO {
    @Insert
    long insertCustomerDetails(CustomerDetails customerDetails);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERDETAILS ORDER BY Created_At")
    LiveData<List<CustomerDetails>> getCustomerDetails();



}
```

Repository class

```
    public class CustomerDetailsRepositary {
    private CustomerDetailsDAO customerDetailsDAO;
    private LiveData<List<CustomerDetails>> customerdetails;
    public CustomerDetailsRepositary(Application application){
        CustomerDatabase customerDatabase = CustomerDatabase.getCustomerDatabaseInstance(application);
        customerDetailsDAO = customerDatabase.customerDetailsDAO();
        customerdetails = customerDetailsDAO.getCustomerDetails();
    }
    public long insert(CustomerDetails customerDetails){

         new InsertCustomerDetailAsyncTask(customerDetailsDAO).execute(customerDetails);
        return customerDetails.getCustomerId();

    }


    public LiveData<List<CustomerDetails>> getCustomerdetails(){
        return customerdetails;
    }
    private static class  InsertCustomerDetailAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<CustomerDetails, Void, Long> {
        private CustomerDetailsDAO customerDetailsDAO;

        private InsertCustomerDetailAsyncTask(CustomerDetailsDAO customerDetailsDAO){
            this.customerDetailsDAO=customerDetailsDAO;
        }
        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(CustomerDetails... customerDetails) {
            return customerDetailsDAO.insertCustomerDetails(customerDetails[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long aLong) {
            super.onPostExecute(aLong);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Room insert function returns the primary key. It does not set the primary key on the object.
When the insert function returns, you have to assign the primary key to the object yourself

```
   @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(CustomerDetails... customerDetails) {
        Long pk = customerDetailsDAO.insertCustomerDetails(customerDetails[0]);
        customerDetails[0].setCustomerId(pk);
        return pk
    }
```

For your example it can look something like this.
Also you have an Int as CustomerId, it should be a Long since it is a primary key.

Comment: still when i call getcustomerid i am getting 0